# Optimizing the loop in a block by block transfer

Tags: c

In the below code, is there a way to avoid the if statement?

```
s = 13;   /*Total size*/
b = 5;    /*Block size*/
x = 0;
b1 = b;
while(x < s)
{
    if(x + b > s)
        b1 = s-x;
    SendData(x, b1);   /*SendData(offset,length);*/
    x += b1;
}
```

Thanks much!

Comment: the question is : Why? The if statements execution time will more than likely be less than the function call

Comment: You'll be spending a lot more time actually sending data than on that `if`. Particularly since the `if` is only sent on the last block!

Comment: On each iteration, the if statement is evaluated. Was wondering if there is a more optimized way to code this loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [conditional move](http://www.rcollins.org/p6/opcodes/CMOV.html) or [branchless integer select](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/2009/01/04/fcmp-conditional-moves-for-branchless-math/) to assign b1 without an if-statement:

```
// if a >= 0, return x, else y
// assumes 32-bit processors
inline int isel( int a, int x, int y ) // inlining is important here
{
    int mask = a >> 31; // arithmetic shift right, splat out the sign bit
    // mask is 0xFFFFFFFF if (a < 0) and 0x00 otherwise.
    return x + ((y - x) & mask);
};

// ...
while(x < s)
{
    b1 = isel( x + b - s, s-x, b1 );
    SendData(x, b1);   /*SendData(offset,length);*/
    x += b1;
}
```

This is only a useful optimization on in-order processors, though. It won't make any difference on a modern PC's x86, which has a fast branch and a reorder unit. It might be useful on some embedded systems (like a Playstation), where [pipeline latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29#Data_hazards) matters more for performance than instruction count. I've used it to shave a few microseconds in tight loops.

In theory a compiler "should" be able to turn a ternary expression (`b = (a > 0 ? x : y)`) into a conditional move, but I've never met one that did.

Of course, in a larger sense everyone who says that this is a pointless optimization compared to the cost of `SendData()` is correct. The difference between a cmov and a branch is about 4 nanoseconds, which is negligible compared to the cost of a network call. Spending your time fixing this branch which happens once per network call is like driving across town to save 1¢ on gasoline.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know maybe you'll think:

```
s = 13;   /*Total size*/
b = 5;    /*Block size*/
x = 0;
while(x + b < s)
{
    SendData(x, b);   /*SendData(offset,length);*/
    x += b;
}
SendData(x, s%b);
```

is better?

Comment: Should be just `while(x < s)`, though. Or even, `for(x = 0; x < s; x += b) { SendData(x,b); }`

Comment: More readable, but if the OP is looking for micro-optimizations the modulo might be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time on pointless micro-optimizations your compiler probably does for you anyway.

Program for the programmer; not the computer. Compilers get better and better, but programmers don't.

If it makes your program more readable (@PaulPRO's answer), then do it. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler always optimizes perfectly?

Comment: @Crashworks No, but tommorow's compiler might. Besides, if you're worried about such a small, unnoticeable speed difference (if there is one) like that, then program in assembly, not C.

Comment: It's a bit extreme to write an entire application in assembly when I could get the same performance from just writing careful C.

Comment: @Crashworks - It's a bit extreme to micro-optimize a loop when the data sending is the real bottleneck.

Comment: @Chris Lutz - That's a perfectly sensible criticism!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to remove `if()`, it might change your logic and you have to spend lot of time for testing. I see only one potential change:

```
s = 13;
b = 5;
x = 0;
b1 = b;
while(x < s)
{
  const unsigned int total = x + b;  // <--- introduce 'total' 
  if(total > s)
    b1 = s-x;
  SendData(x, b1);
  x = total;   // <--- reusing it
}
```

Comment: This one change is questionable for so simple an operation, and will almost certainly be performed by the compiler.

Comment: @Chris, yes for PODs it *might* be performed by compiler. Still it's a good habit to have DRY approach (Don't Repeat Yourself). Such attitude helps when `x,b` etc. where user defined types.

Comment: PODs are all there is in C, and I don't see a C++ tag.